# jquery validation on multiple fields

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to do validation in jquery on multiple fields when the form field names/id's are not fixed (vary for each form)? For example:

```
<form>
   <p>Select Colour</p>
       <select name="M100" id="M100">
          <option value="" disabled="disabled">Please Select</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
       </select>
       <div id="M100error"></div>

   <p>Select Size</p>
       <select name="M101" id="M101">
          <option value="" disabled="disabled">Please Select</option>
          <option value="S">Small</option>
          <option value="M">Medium</option>
          <option value="L">Large</option>
       </select>
       <div id="M101error"></div>

   <p>Select Gender</p>
       <input type="radio" name="M102" id="M102" value="male">Male<br>
       <input type="radio" name="M102" id="M102" value="female">Female<br>
       <div id="M102error"></div>

   <input type="submit" value="submit form">
</form>
```

Serialize() do not pick up the disabled option values.

In Jquery I need to do something like this

1. Obtain all the divs or form field names in the form and go through each one (M100,M101.M102)
2. Check they are not empty
3. If empty/not selected then output message to (M100error, M101error, M102error)
4. If no errors then run a script

Thank You
Sienna

Comment: Create a jquery validation function script whose argument is a form fields (input fields) as you call them then inside it get ID of input field so that if field is not selected or populated, you get ID of field and prepend it with text string 'error' and fire alert message with that string otherwise exit jquery validation function.

Call your function every time you need to validate input fields by calling it in a loop where you pass arguments of all input fields in a form

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `required` attribute on the `<select>`. When set, options with empty values are considered invalid and will not submit the form.

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u23ek28c/)